# Checking if a functional $F(x)$ is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

There is a functional given:
$$F(x) = \sqrt{2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2}$$
Of course $x\in\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow x = (x_1, x_2)$
It is easy to check that:
1) $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ $F(x) \ge 0$
2) $F(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$
3) $ F(\lambda x) = | \lambda | F(x)$
I failed however to show that $F(x+y) \le F(x) + F(y)$. How should it be proven?

Comment: you mean $F(x+y)\leq F(x)+ F(y)$ ?

Comment: @Netchaiev Yes, of course. I'm changing it.

Comment: And in (3) $\lambda\ge 0$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Why? The definition doesn't say anything about the sign of $\lambda$. Actually there is $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{F}$

Comment: Can be true for $\lambda < 0$?

Comment: Alternatively, $F(\lambda x) = |\lambda|F(x)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I'm sorry! It was a stupid typo. Everything is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality:

\begin{align}
F(x+y)^2 &= 2(x_1+y_1)^2+3(x_2+y_2)^2 \\
&= \underbrace{2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2}_{F(x)^2} + \underbrace{2y_1^2+3y_2^2}_{F(x)^2}+2(2x_1y_1 + 3x_2y_2)\\
&\stackrel{CSB}{\le} F(x)^2 + F(y)^2 + 2\sqrt{2x_1^2+3x_2^2}\sqrt{2y_2^2+3y_2^2}\\
&= F(x)^2 + F(y)^2 + 2F(x)F(y)\\
&= (F(x) + F(y))^2
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
(F(x)+F(y))^2 &= 2x_1^2 + 2y_1^2+3x_2^2 + 3y_2^2+2\sqrt{2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2}\sqrt{2y_1^2 + 3y_2^2}  \\
F(x+y)^2 &= 2(x_1 + y_1)^2 +3(x_2 + y_2)^2
\end{align*}
So you just have to verify that 
$$ (4x_1y_1 + 6x_2y_2)^2 \leq 4(2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2)(2y_1^2 + 3y_2^2)$$
which is equivalent after expending and simplification to 
$$ 0 \leq -2 x_1x_2y_1y_2 + x_1^2y_2^2+ x_2^2y_1^2 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad 0\leq ( x_1y_2- x_2y_1)^2$$
which is always true.

Comment: That gives me $(x_2x_1-x_1y_2)^2 \ge 0$, doesn't it?

Comment: @Hendrra please see my edit

Comment: Thank you! That'a a nice and simple solution.

Comment: How do we know that $4x_1y_1 + 6x_2y_2 \ge 0$? If it isn't we can't square this inequality: $4x_1y_1 + 6x_2y_2 \le 2\sqrt{2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2}\sqrt{2y_1^2 + 3y_2^2}$

Comment: @Hendrra The reasoning is in the opposite way : we verify that $(4x_1y_1 + 6x_2y_2)^2 \leq 4(2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2)(2y_1^2 + 3y_2^2)$ (that's what I did), then you can take the square root of this inequality and will obtain $$     |4x_1y_1 + 6x_2y_2| \leq 2\sqrt{2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2}\sqrt{2y_1^2 + 3y_2^2}$$ and finally  $$   4x_1y_1 + 6x_2y_2\leq |4x_1y_1 + 6x_2y_2| \leq 2\sqrt{2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2}\sqrt{2y_1^2 + 3y_2^2}$$

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it :)

Answer (score 2):

General principle: if $f:E\longrightarrow E$ is a linear isomorphism and $\|\|$ is a norm in $E$, then $\|x\|_f = \|f(x)\|$ is a norm in $E$. Proof of subadditivity:
$$
\|x + y\|_f = \|f(x + y)\| = \|f(x) + f(y)\|\le\|f(x)\| + \|f(y)\| =\|x\|_f + \|y\|_f.
$$
In your case, $f(x_1,x_2) = (\sqrt2\,x_1,\sqrt3\,x_2)$.

Comment: That's a good one. Where can I find to proof of this property?

Comment: @Hendrra You have it in front of your eyes!

Comment: I mean the proof of the general principle :)

Comment: @Hendrra Martin proved the subadditivity which is the only non trivial part.

Comment: (1), (2), (3) are easy. Try yourself.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I'll try! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Does your book prove that the standard Euclidean norm is an inner poduct? I would recommend repeating their proof:

Define an inner product $\langle v, w \rangle $ so that $\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle v,  v\rangle}$. Show that $\langle , \rangle$ satisfies the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Then use that to conclude the triangle inequality. (This is what the other answer is suggesting, though more explicitly)

If you happen to be given that the Euclidean norm is actually a norm, then you might want to try reducing this norm to that norm.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. There is even no book at my University. Can you recommend me one?

Comment: What course are you learning? Do you have a course website or could you let me know where you are at in your "mathematical education"?

Comment: It's name is just "Functional Analysis". I've done a lot of Real Analysis, Linear Algebra, Abstract Algebra, Topology and Measure Theory.

Comment: Just see Chapter 1 of Baby Rudin, where he defines the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then uses it to prove the triangle inequality. It is exactly the same thing that one does for Hilbert spaces: define an inner product, prove Cauchy-Schwartz, prove triangle inequality. See Stein and Shakarachi's Real Analysis where they do Hilbert Space theory.